# Android Room taking ~40 seconds to execute first query

Tags: android, android-room

We're importing a DB with Android Room using the createFromFile method. It's a heavy DB (~500MB).

The first query takes ~30-40 seconds to run, and after that it starts working pretty smooth.

This is how we're creating our database:

```
dbFile: File? = null,
...
synchronized(this) {
    var instance = INSTANCE

    if (dbFile != null) {
       instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
           context.applicationContext,
           MyDatabase::class.java,
           "$dbName.db"
       )
           .createFromFile(dbFile)
           .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
           .build()
           INSTANCE = instance
    }
    return instance
}
...
```

And then we're just running a simple query against that database. That query is taking ~30-40 seconds the first time, and then it starts working very well...

Any idea why this might happen? is that the time it takes to actually open the DB?

Thanks
Cristian.

Comment: "Any idea why this might happen?" -- it is copying the database from your file to the actual database location.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks! What looks weird is that it seems to be copying the DB from the file to the actual location when we run the first query? and not when we're actually doing the "createFromFile().build()".

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I have not looked at the implementation of `createFromFile(dbFile)`. It is possible that they do it lazily, as the rest of the `RoomDatabase` setup process is usually pretty quick, so we don't necessarily do that setup on a background thread. OTOH, database I/O is normally slow, so we're normally on a background thread, so doing the copy on the first access would get us on a background thread without additional development work. That's just a guess, and I suspect they're not targeting databases the size of yours.